# Convert Observable<List<String>> into Observable<List<Integer>> with RxJava mapping

Tags: android, type-conversion, mapping, rx-java

I have a function `getColorList` which returns an `ArrayList` of `String` type

```
private static List<String> getColorList() {
        ArrayList<String> colors = new ArrayList<>();
        colors.add("red");
        colors.add("green");
        colors.add("blue");
        colors.add("pink");
        colors.add("brown");
        return colors;
}
```

I want to get a `Observable<List<Integer>>` from that string `ArrayList` where the list is the lengths of those strings.

```
Observable<List<Integer>> listLengthObservable = Observable.fromArray(getColorList()).map( //Mapping function );
```

What would be the mapping function for this conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can flatten the list, map each string to each length, and then collect it back to list.

```
Single<List<Integer>> listLengthObservable = Observable.fromIterable(getColorList())
            .map(s -> s.length())
            .toList();
```

More elegant method is to use `reduceWith`:

```
Single<List<Integer>> listLengthObservable = Observable.fromIterable(getColorList())
            .reduceWith(() -> new ArrayList<Integer>(), (integers, s) -> {
                integers.add(s.length());
                return integers;
            });
```

which goes over all the items in the `Observable` and collect them with the input integers list you provide.

Both operators return `Single` (as there is by definition single emission), you can easily convert it to `Observable` using `toObservable()` if you must need it.

Comment: Thank you for your solution.

Comment: Arguably, an Observable<Foo> is preferable to a Single<List<Foo>> (unless one absolutely needs all the elements at the same time).